# Perl with backticks - I do not understand the operation inside the backticks

Tags: perl, backticks

I'm a perl novice. What's happening inside the backticks of the following?

`$selfext` and `$banner` are previously defined. The statement below is executed in Linux and I don't understand where the banner function is coming from? When I print `$_` I get a null string.

```
$_=`banner $selfext $banner`;
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of `$selfext` and `$banner`? In Perl, an expression in backticks is executed as a system call and its output is returned as a string. Here, you are assigning that output to `$_`. If it is empty, then the `banner` command probably didn't produce any output.

Comment: Note that the code appears to suffer from [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bugs.

Comment: joanis, Thanks.  selfext is null and banner="results"

Answer (score 2):

This is [invoking a shell](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#%60STRING%60) which is executing the `banner` command. `banner` is a normal UNIX program like `uniq`, `sort` or even `perl` itself, i.e. this is not some perl function.  It is not installed on all systems though (same as with `perl`) and therefore the execution might fail. For more see [man banner](https://www.manpagez.com/man/6/banner/).

Comment: Steffen, Thanks!   the script is running on RedHat7.1 and "banner" does not exist.   I should've mentioned the script is about 20 years old and began its life runnning on Unix machines like AIX.

Comment: `banner` is also part of [Perl Power Tools](http://perlpowertools.com) should you need it for something.

Comment: @BilgeRat There's probably a system package for it (`yum install banner`?).

Comment: Package name is `bsd-games`.